# How to have multiple values in -DconfigFile in command line java?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am running my jar file as below :

```
java -jar xyz.jar -DconfigFile=prop1.properties
```

But how can I pass multiple properties file in same command, something like below :

```
java -jar xyz.jar -DconfigFile=prop1.properties,prop2.properties
```

so above command is not working. How can I pass multiple properties file in command?

Comment: Modify your code inside `xyz.jar` to process the `args` passed to `main` so the code processing the argument that starts with `-DconfigFile=` such that the rest of that argument is a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat prop1.properties prop2.properties > props_combined.properties; 
java -jar xyz.jar -DconfigFile=props_combined.properties
```

Comment: Thanks @varontron for your answer, but I cannot combine those two property files.

Comment: @SagarJoon Why not?